# Bash refer to previous arguments in same line

Tags: bash, zsh, shortcut

I seem to remember that `bash` had a bang-shortcut for referring to something in the same line. I know and use `!$`, `!!` and friends regularly. I recall reading being able to do something like the following:

```
mkdir tmp && cd !_
```

where `!_` represents the combination I can't remember. (The goal of the above is to make a directory and immediately `cd` into it upon success.) Google only yields reposts of the same 2 reference tables which don't have this combination.

Right now I'm using the less-efficient

```
mkdir tmp
cd !$
```

which gets the job done but not the way I want to do it.

**Does anyone know this elusive shortcut?**

In case it matters, I use `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`, not vanilla `bash`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mkdir tmp && cd "$_"
```

is what you're looking for, I believe (you can drop the double quotes if you're sure that quoting is not needed).

`$_` expands differently in different contexts, but the one that matters here (from `man bash` , v3.2.51):

> expands  to  the last argument to the previous command, after expansion.

**Background**:

Note: the following discusses `bash`, but it seems to apply to `zsh` in principle as well.

`$_` is a so-called **special parameter**, which you'll find listed among others (without the `$` prefix) in the `Special Parameters` section of `man bash`:

- Works both in interactive shells and in scripts.
- Works at the *individual command* level, not at the *line* level.

By contrast, `!`-prefixed tokens (such as `!$` to recall the most recent line's last token) relate to the shell's **[command] history expansion** (section `HISTORY EXPANSION` of `man bash`):

- By default they work only in interactive shells, but that can be changed with `set -o history` and `set -o histexpand` (thanks, @chepner)).
- Work at the *line* level (more accurately: everything that was submitted with one `Enter` keystroke, no matter how many individual commands or lines it comprised).

Answer (score 7):

`!#` refers to the command line so far, and you can extract specific words from it:

```
mkdir tmp && cd !#:1
```

The same syntax works in `zsh` as well.

Comment: Works well in the case at hand, but the `1` in `!#:1` is an _absolute  token index_ from the _start of the line_, which means the solution doesn't generalize well; e.g., `mkdir -p tmp/sub && cd !#:1` would break; you'd have to pay attention and count all tokens on the line to find the right index. Also, since the shell _expands_ the history reference and stores the _expanded_ command in the history (in addition to printing it before executing), you _couldn't go back and edit the command as typed_ - e.g., to create another dir. - you'd only get the _expanded_ version. (cont'd below).

Comment: (cont'd from above) Provided the intent is to get the _previous simple command's_ _LAST_ (expanded) token (if not, then the `!#`-based solution IS needed): all these problems go away when you use `$_`, e.g. `mkdir -p tmp/sub && cd "$_"` (I double-quoted `$_`, to be safe).  I know the OP was looking for a history-expansion token, which you provided, but given the question's _intent_, I think `$_` is the better choice.

Comment: There is a shell option (`histverify`) that allows you to edit the command before executing it. `$_` *only* works if the intent is to use the last argument. `!#` may require a little more work, but it *can* work with any command line you might use.

Comment: That's a good summary, thanks; didn't know about `shopt -s histverify` - handy (for bash; zsh equivalent: `setopt HIST_VERIFY`). (And, just to be clear: I learned from your post and from your comments on mine.)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
mkdir foo; cd $_
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

(Old news, but in case someone else lands here looking for this, like I just did)

---

OP seemed to be looking for `!#[X][-Y]` zsh syntax

where X and Y are indexes for shell words in history event for current line

X and Y are assumed to refer to the start or end of line -
 respectively - when omitted

(keep in mind that end of line in this context is actually the occurrence of the `!#[X][-Y]` event call within the line)

this gives us the following variants:

- `!#` *current line up to `!#`*
- `!#-Y` *current line up the `Y`-th word*
- `!#X` *`X`-th word only*
- `!#X-Y` *words `X` through `Y`*
- `!#X-` *from `X`-th word, until `!#X-`*

## in direct response to example given:

```
mkdir tmp && cd !#2
```

or, taking it a step further:

```
alias mktmpd='mkdir -p tmp /tmp/${PWD:t}; cd ${(@)${~:-${=^:-!#2-3}(N/)}[1]}; pwd; ls'
```

the path `/tmp/${PWD:t}` would be created also and act as an alternative to `cd` to if for some reason `./tmp` could not be created (which would have failed silently)

this assumes user can `mkdir` in `/tmp` and is willing to let some useless paths be generated (and left untouched) when `./tmp` is perfectly usable and in fact chosen

potential problem arises when `/tmp/${PWD:t}` already exists and its contents are unrelated and not be disturbed, hence the `pwd; ls`

aliasing helps with use cases such as `somecommand; mktmpd` where normally the !#2-3 would no longer refer to the appropriate parameters `tmp` `/tmp/${PWD:t}`

Note however that I am decidedly not advocating for this use case as an especially helpful one (or even its fitness as an example, really - but I wanted to point out the alias particularity since I have yet to see it mentioned elsewhere)